# Do random LP problems have optima with probability $\frac 12$?

Tags: probability, linear-programming, duality-theorems, polyhedra

Robert J. Vanderbei, in his book "Linear Programming, Foundations and Extensions", Chapter 5 "Duality Theory", section Notes, states that

> The solution to Exercise 5.13 suggests that a random Linear Programming problem is infeasible with probability $1/4$, unbounded with probability $1/4$, and has an optimal solution with probability $1/2$.

(There is an online version of [**Vanderbei's book**](https://support.dce.felk.cvut.cz/pub/hanzalek/_private/ref/Vanderbei_Linear_Programming.pdf); go to p.98 of the pdf file, which is p.82 of the book)

Now, if a random problem has an optimum with probability $1/2$, then the rest follows by symmetry. Unfortunately, the author does not provide any further details on what makes him think so, and neither does he say for which kind of probability distribution such a claim may be true. The solution to the mentioned exercise boils down to the fact that for an unfeasible problem (with $P=\emptyset$) we have

> $$\max\{f(x)~|~x\in P\}=-\infty<\infty=\min\{f(x)~|~x\in P\}$$

which is somewhat counter-intuitive, and to the fact that a problem and its dual may both be infeasible. However, those facts do not help me at all to understand Vanderbei's line of reasoning.

Can some of you see why he reaches the above conclusion?

Comment: What is "the solution to Exercise 5.9"?

Comment: The number of the exercise varies, depending on the edition of the book; I now adjusted it to the online version linked to in the post.

Comment: @Bey: "Exercise 5.9" (which in the online version became Exercise 5.13) can be found at the address (now) given in the post. The solution to the exercise is "left to the reader to supply".

Comment: I looked at 5.13 in the link - as you astutely pointed out, one cannot assign probabilities without a distribution. I don't see how this problem provides a basis for a probability. My *guess* is that he is appealing to the principle of indifference: a problem has an optimum or not. Then, conditional on it not having an optimum, it can be infeasible or unbounded. Placing equal probability on these outcomes leads to the result but it's not clear how he defined a distribution over LPs in the first place.

Comment: The principle of indifference can be invoked quite independently of the quoted problem or its solution. As was the case of Borgwardt's probability analysis, it may be that Vanderbei was thinking of a whole class of distributions,  defined by a set of properties they ought to satisfy. For instance: "the probability for $A$ to be the coefficient matrix of a problem should be the same as for its negative,  $-\!A$, to be such". Those kind of assertions may be reasonable, though rather weak assumptions.

Comment: You're right; I was simply speculating a basis for going from an enumeration of possibilities to a probability statement. As you indicate, some form of symmetry argument seems needed.